# Graphite not aggregating data

Tags: graph, graphite

I'm using Graphite and Carbon-cache and trying to understand why it doesn't appear to be applying aggregation to data.

I have a whipser database:

```
whisper-create.py  /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/test/test.wsp 60:1y
```

From the metadata I am using an average aggregation method:

```
Meta data:
  aggregation method: average
  max retention: 31536000
  xFilesFactor: 0.5
```

And I am writing two values to it:

```
echo "test.test 1 `date +%s`" | nc localhost 2003; 
echo "test.test 100 `date +%s`" | nc localhost 2003;
```

When I look at my whisper databse I see the following value:

```
42: 1395315780,        100
```

I would have expected this value to be `100+1 / 2 = 50.5`

It appears to be using the last value, rather than an average of the two values.

I feel like I may be missing something here. Could anyone explain?

Comment: I think Graphite replaces values *for the same timestamp* with the last one submitted. You should wait between your samples. Additionally the aggregation method is only used when downsampling from a frequent to a more infrequent series in your whisper database - but you only defined one of them. See http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-carbon.html#storage-aggregation-conf

Comment: @cmur2 When you say "same timestamp" do you mean same milliseconds or same interval (in my example 60s). I let time pass between those 2 echo statements so they won't be for the exact same unix timestamp but are both within the 60s interval.

Comment: Graphite/Whisper will record one value per -in your case- 60s. The aggregation is only involved in downsampling multiple 60s-intervals into another one, which, in your example, does not exist.

Comment: @cmur2 Aah, I see. So how can I achieve aggregation? I'm trying to send it through the carbon-aggregator but I seem to be getting the same results

Comment: People use e.g. statsd for your use case in front of carbon - afair carbon-aggregator is only for load-balancing etc.

Comment: @cmur2 After a bit of fiddling (and creation of `aggregation-rules.conf`) i've been able to achieve aggregation using carbon-aggregator (not statsd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to use the carbon-aggregator, not the carbon-cache.

The carbon-cache will always replace the value, no matter what. If time per point is 1 second and you send more than one value within a second then the last value is what will be stored.

If you want more than one value to be kept you need to use the carbon-aggregator (running on a different port) and configure how it should aggregate the data (sum, average).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and no access on the graphite / whisper settings.
There is another solution. Aggregate data externally and the send it to graphite data port.
https://github.com/floringavrila/graphite-feeder

Comment: Hi Gravrila and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please can you add a little more detail to your answer? It would help if you explain *how* this answers the question, and how it fits together.